# How to test with JavaScript if a user has allowed multiple file downloads in the browser?

Tags: javascript, download

I'm working on creating a relatively simple thing that lets a user pick from multiple thumbnails and initiate a download of the original files.

I'm aware of implementations where you stream blobs and then create files out of those, but I was wondering if there was a way to use the `navigator.permissions.query` API or something similar to test whether Downloading multiple files is allowed by the user, because optimally the downloads would be parallel instead of queued.

The basic prompt in the browser is such that I've already had messages about "downloads not working" as the native prompt is relatively small and in the corner of the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [Permission registry](https://w3c.github.io/permissions/#permission-registry) does not contain automatic downloads yet, and when it does (if it does one day) I'm not sure if they include the "multiple downloads" setting since it is a global setting (not related to a particular domain) so it might be an information that should not be exposed (maybe I'm extrapolating too much on this, though).